# Angular 2 not working on android 4.1

Tags: android, angularjs

So i have an Angular 2 application that runs just fine on android api 19+,

But for some reason anything below that android OS, its not loading/render the angular.

Am i missing a shim/ poly fill or something?

I am not doing anything fancy. Here is my index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<title>Angular 2 Messenger</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/login-styles.css'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/conversation-list-styles.css'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/conversation-styles.css'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/participants-styles.css'/>


    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<my-app>
    <div class="homeLoading">
        <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:45px;"></i>
        <p style="font-size:24px;">TEST</p>
        <p style="margin-top:-5px;"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:25px;"></i></p>
    </div>
</my-app>
<script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

It gets into the index.html, but not in to the angular 2 directives.

Comment: As far I know angular2 doesn't work for android < 4.4. It concerns only native browser (WebView component), so in chrome mobile it should work.
I'm also wondering what so tricky they are used in angular2. Haven't found it yet

Comment: seems i found the reason: "...this is because the webview version from Android 4.x and 5.x doesn't support native Set and Map"

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/898

Answer (score 0):

i resoleved that issue.
my console showed:

1. INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 (seems webkit bug)
2. __extends is not defined

to fix this i did:

ignored INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
fix __extends issue (https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/26)( noEmitHelpers didnt help me and i used helpers as temporary fix from that page
then added polyfill for proxy and delete console.clear(...) from my build